# Asp.net identity confirmation mails going to spam 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am using asp.net identity for registering users, but confirmation mails going to spam instead of inbox:
[image]

Also as you can see it says Images are not displayed while i am not sending any... 
Here is my code :

```
   public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {            
            string html = message.Body;
            string plain = message.Body;
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, new ContentType("text/html")));
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(plain, new ContentType("text/plain")));
            msg.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@leavingstone.net", "nebula");
            msg.To.Add(message.Destination);
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            msg.Subject = "აქტივაცია";

            new SmtpClient("smtp.mandrillapp.com")
            {
                Port = 25,
                Credentials = ((ICredentialsByHost)new NetworkCredential("xxx"))
            }.Send(msg);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```

Comment: Realistically speaking, this has _nothing_ to do with the code, ASP.Net and such. Why your email is tagged as spam can range from content, IP spam databases, spf/dkim setup or lack of, all the way to recipient/user preferences, spam firewalls,  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well the message is pretty clear.

> It contains content that's typically used in spam messages

You should try to make changes in message and subject content

Comment: Why  what is the problem? i am sending just confirmation link

Comment: I've just change subject ='აქტივაცია' to subject = activation and problem has been solved. But i had utf-8 encoding and why that thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

I've just change subject ='აქტივაცია' to subject = activation and problem has been solved. But i had utf-8 encoding and why that thing happens?